# how to get value from posted form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a new admin form.In this form i have just username and password fields. I just want when i add new admin, show the username.

When i use `params[:admin]` it is getting `{"username"=>"admin", "password"=>"123123"}`

When i use `params[:admin].permit(:username)` it is getting `{"username"=>"admin"}`. But i just want get the value, like "admin".

```
admins_controller.rb create
def create
    @admin = Admin.new(admin_params)
    if @admin.save
      redirect_to admin_admins_path
      flash[:notice] = "new admin added.. #{params[:admin].permit(:username)}"

    else
      render 'new'
      flash[:alert] = 'there is a error...'
    end
  end
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
params[:admin][:username]
```

Comment: I hope it helped! Please feel free to upvote/accept if you like.

Answer (score 1):

`params` is a hash, so you can do:

```
params = {one: 1, two: 2}
params[:one] # returns 1
params[:two] # returns 2
```

if you have a hash inside a hash you can do:

```
params = {numbers: {one: 1, two: 2}}
params[:numbers][:one] # returns 1
params[:numbers][:two] # returns 2
```

Comment: What is it then?

Comment: since Rails 5.1 `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from Hash.